# Array size changing after creation

Tags: java, arrays

can anyone explain whats happening here. I was under the impression that an array's size can't be changed once its been created and declared.

```
public class ArrayManipulation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a[] = {1, 2, 3};//new int[3];
        int b[] = new int[a.length-1];

        System.out.print("a = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        //This is the bit I am confused about.. I was expecting an error here
        a = b;

        System.out.print("a = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
           System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are objects, and yes, once they are created their size doesnt change.

in the line:

```
a= b;
```

you are pointing `a` reference to `b` object. So your initial object that `a` was referencing is still in VM until it s garbage collected.

But your array size didnt change but you reference is pointing to a differet array/object now

Answer (score 0):

Both `a` and `b` are of type `int[]`. So `a = b` simply assign the value of `a` to the value of `b`.

After this assignment, both `a` and `b` refer to the same array and the initial array referenced by `a` can be collected by the *garbage collector* as it cannot be accessed anymore.

Comment: Yes the size is not part of the type/class. Some languages (like Pascal, Algol68) offer this. But in java an array variable is just a pointer, and the array value contains the field length.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the reference that `a` points to when you say `a = b`.

Since arrays are objects, setting one equal to another changes the reference. Both arrays still exist, but both references - `a` and `b` - point to the location of `b`. The only way to actually delete the array `a` is to garbage collect it.

You aren't actually changing the array size, it just seems like it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is the bit I am confused about.. I was expecting an error here
    a = b;
```

Yup, you're confused abt the right thing! `a` and `b` have their own memory allocated for themselves. With `a = b` you are making `a` point to the memory allocated for `b`.

Perhaps adding these additional sysouts to code would help, see the output:

```
public class ArrayManipulation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a[] = {1, 2, 3};//new int[3];
        int b[] = new int[a.length-1];


        System.out.print("a = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];

        System.out.print("NEW -- before a=b. a = " + a);
        System.out.print("NEW -- before a=b. b = " + b);
        //This is the bit I am confused about.. I was expecting an error here
        a = b;
        System.out.print("NEW -- after a=b. a = " + a);
        System.out.print("NEW -- after a=b. b = " + b);

        System.out.print("a = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
           System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();       
    }
}
```